# Standard deviation of means of samples

Tags: sampling, standard-deviation, standard-error

**Problem**: Suppose we have a population of size $m$ and we're taking simple random samples (without replacement) of size $n$. Let's denote the mean of the entire population by $\mu$. Assume we take $k$ such samples and calculate their means $\mu_1, \dots, \mu_k$. Calculate the standard deviation of the observed sample means and compare it to the standard error of the mean of the sample.

I don't understand what is meant by "standard deviation of the observed sample means". I'm assuming I have to calculate the expression
$$\frac{1}{k - 1} \sum_{i = 1} ^k (\mu_i - \mu).$$
Is this correct?

Comment: I would rather interpret it as $$\hat \sigma_{\hat \mu} \triangleq \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^k (\hat \mu_i - \hat \mu)^2}$$
where $$\hat \mu \triangleq \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^k \hat \mu_i$$

but I am not entirely sure from the wording.

Comment: One cannot "calculate the standard deviation of the *observed* sample means" because no information about the specific observations has been provided.  The intention could be to derive the distribution of the SD of the $\mu_i$ *qua* random variables; or it could be to compute the (common) SD of all the $\mu_i$ -- which is the SE of the mean -- or maybe it's something else.  You ought to ask the person posing this problem for clarification.

Comment: The convention is Greek letters for parameters ($\mu,\sigma,\rho$, etc), capital 'Roman' letters for random variables ($X, Y, U, V$ etc) and lower case for observations/realized values ($x_1, y_i, z_n$ etc). Please avoid using Greek letter's like $\mu$ if you don't mean the population parameter, since the unnecessary violation of convention will lead to miscommunication. Presumably the intent of the problem is to take $m$ samples, which yields $m$ sample means, $\bar{x}^{(1)},\bar{x}^{(2)},...,\bar{x}^{(m)}$ and then compute the ordinary sample standard deviation of those $m$ values.